# Why Do I Get "Animation was deleted without rendering anything"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pysimplegui

My code has a list of stocks and its supposed to display a graph of the "stock price" (fake data) if you click on a stock. It works when I click one stock, but when I try to click on another one I get the error in the title. The error says "To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable that exists for as long as you need the Animation." How could I implement this? Thanks for the help!

Here is the relevant code:

```
def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return figure_canvas_agg

fig = plt.figure()

draw_figure(_VARS['window']['-Graph-'].TKCanvas, fig)





#------------------------------------------------While loop/Search bar Code-----------------------------------------------------------# 

while True:
    
    event, values = _VARS['window'].read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):                # always check for closed window
        break

    else:
        
        if values['-INPUT-'] != '':                         # if a keystroke entered in search field
            search = values['-INPUT-']
            new_values = [x for x in stockDic if search in x]  # do the filtering
            _VARS['window']['-LIST-'].update(new_values)     # display in the listbox
        else:
            # display original unfiltered list
            _VARS['window']['-LIST-'].update(stockDic)
        # if a list item is chosen
        if event == '-LIST-' and len(values['-LIST-']):
            stockName = values['-LIST-']
            name = stockName[0]
            _VARS['window']['-Name-'].update("Name: {}".format(stockDic[name]["Name"]))
            _VARS['window']['-Price-'].update("Price: {}".format(stockDic[name]["Price"]))
            _VARS['window']['-Current_Gain-'].update("Current Gain: {}".format(stockDic[name]["currentGain"]))

            moment=time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d__%H",time.localtime())

            plt.clf()

            ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

            def animate(i):
                global anims
                anims = []
                pullData = open("csv_files/{}".format(stockDic[name]["Name"]) + "/{}".format(stockDic[name]["Name"]) + ".csv " + moment,"r").read()
                dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
                xar = []
                yar = []
                for eachLine in dataArray:
                    if len(eachLine)>1:
                        x,y = eachLine.split(',')
                        xar.append(int(x))
                        yar.append(int(y))
                        

                    ax1.clear() 
                    ax1.plot(xar,yar)

            ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=150)
            anims.append(ani)
```

Comment: It will be better if with simple, short and executable code to demo your issue to people may help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).